# Swift - TableView Cell Selection

Tags: swift, tableview, selection, cell

I make in Swift a `UITableview`, and I want make that when somebody click on the cell he will be show a selection of this cell and when somebody click on the next cell the selection disappear from first selection and show in the next selection.

Example: I click on **Cell1** - show now selection of this cell, When I click on **Cell2** the **Cell1** selection disappear and **Cell2** show now selection.

Hope somebody can help me

Comment: Isn't this the default behavior of tableview?

Answer (score 0):

Usethe `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` method and access the cell from it:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
  //Do whatever you want with the cell
}
```